# Изменение "не" на "ни"

Tags: семантика

Представим себе такой диалог:

— Я вам только что это сказал.
— Ничего вы мне не сказали!

А теперь так:

— Я вам только что это сказал и объяснил.
— Ничего вы мне ни сказали, ни объяснили!

Правильно ли так ответить во втором случае, и значит ли это то же самое, что и *"Ничего вы мне не сказали и ничего не объяснили!"*?

Comment: _— Ничего вы мне **ни** сказали, **ни** объяснили!_ === Гм... А почему Вы считаете, что в этом предложении должна использоваться частица _**ни**_? По-моему, нужно _**не**_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В приведенном примере автор может по своему усмотрению использовать отрицательную частицу НЕ или усилительную частицу НИ, но при этом следует немного изменить конструкцию предложения:

**Вариант без усиления**: Ничего вы мне **не сказали** и ничего вы мне н**е объяснили**! Ничего вы мне **не сказали и не объяснили**!

**Вариант с усилением**: Ничего вы мне **ни сказали, ни объяснили**! (А также: ни доказали и т. д.) Имеется в виду, что никаким способом не ввели в курс дела.

**Краткая теория по теме**

1) Повторяющаяся частица НИ встречается в двух вариантах: А) в составе союза НИ…НИ при имеющемся отрицании, Б) для выражения полноты отрицания.

2) Усилительная частица НИ входит в состав повторяющегося соединительного союза НИ…НИ (**при наличии слова с частицей  НЕ**, которая выражает отрицание). Союз НИ…НИ  используется в предложениях с однородными членами: Я не знаю ни его, ни вас. Твои глаза не выражали ни вдохновенья, ни печали.

3) Слово с отрицанием **может быть пропущено**, но его можно восстановить по смыслу: Ни отзыва, ни слова, ни привета (нет), пустынею меж нами мир лежит. Ни в сказке сказать, ни пером описать (нельзя).

4) Частица НИ в составе союза НИ…НИ  может использоваться **для выражения полноты отрицания.** При полноте отрицания отрицаются два признака, предмета или действия, но **подразумевается полное отрицание всех других возможных признаков, предметов и действий. Это тот случай, когда частица НИ одновременно имеет значение и отрицания и усиления:** Ворон ни варят, ни жарят. Здесь ни проехать, ни пройти. Также: Ни рыба ни мясо, ни  много ни мало,  ни жив ни мертв, ни слуху ни духу.

Comment: Спасибо, Sybilla!

Comment: Вариант без усиления: Ничего вы мне ни сказали и ничего вы мне не объяснили! Разве здесь правильно "ни сказали"?

Comment: Спасибо, ошибка в записи исправлена

Answer (score 0):

> Правильно ли так ответить во втором случае, и значит ли это то же самое, что и "Ничего вы мне не сказали и ничего не объяснили!"?

Хороший вопрос.

Здесь строго по смыслу надо "ничего вы мне НЕ (сделали), ни сказали, ни объяснили" Т. е. отрицание и повторяющийся союз НИ - НИ ставятся по разным мотивам.

Но судя по всему в таких случаях (особенно при глаголах) отрицание НЕ поглощается рядом стоящим союзом.

*"Ни за синими морями, ни за дальними лесами. Ни на небе на земле, жил дурак в одном селе." (сказка)*

"Пропал ни за что ни про что" (фразеологизм)

Более детально можно объяснить так. "Ничего" само по себе берет на себя функцию отрицания, поэтому второе отрицание не обязательно. А союз ни - ни выступает как усилительный при отрицании. 
Особенно наглядно выступает эта функция во фразеологизмах.
Вот смотрите, сколько их Лопатин приводит.
http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=4138
И все прекрасно стыкуются с "никого", "ничего" и подобными без дополнительного отрицания.

Comment: Спасибо!*******